# Как сделать сортировку списка без list.sort()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сделать сортировку списка без использования *list.sort()*, часть кода:

```
a = []

while True:
    b = int(input())
    if b != -1:
        a.append(b)
    else:
        break

print(a)

# Сумма
i = 0
l = len(a)
s = 0
while i < l:
    s += a[i]
    i += 1
print(s)

# Произведение
i = 0
l = len(a)
s = 1
while i < l:
    s *= a[i]
    i += 1
print(s)

# Подсчёт большего
i = 0
s = a[0]
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] > s:
        s = a[i]
    i += 1
print(s)

# Подсчёт меньшего
i = 0
s = a[0]
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] < s:
        s = a[i]
    i += 1
print(s)

# сортировка
i = 0
l = len(a)
while i < l:
    j = 0
    while j < i - 1:
        if a[j] > a[j+1]:
            # Хз как
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(a)
```

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

Думаю Сортировка пузырьком например поможет разобраться в сортировке.
Там точно есть конструкция которая вам нужна.

```
array = [5,7,4,3,8,2]
for run in range(len(array)-1):
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        if array[i]>array[i+1]:
            array[i],array[i+1]= array[i+1],array[i] # ваше хз как
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Хз как
> ```

И так:

```
a[j], a[j+1] = [j+1], a[j]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\begor\Desktop\Python\1.py", line 55, in <module>
    a[j], a[j+l] = [j+1], a[j]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @EgorAkaDeer, это ваша ошибка, не моя. Вместо цифры `1` вы написали букву `l`. Между прочим, не было бы лучше использовать вместо имени `l` что-то другое?